# How to generate100 UUIDS and use it later in Jmeter?

Tags: java, jmeter

I am new to Jmeter and working on performance testing for my CRUD operations(UserManagement).
I want to create 100 users and get those users by using Jmeter HttpRequest.
In my create request I have to pass auto generated ID as id.So How can I generate 100 auto generated ids
 and use it while doing the Create/Get user.

Comment: CURD operations? Not CRUD? Did you mean something like this `List<Integer> ids = IntStream.range(0, 100).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());` ? [Here's](https://www.baeldung.com/java-uuid) smthg on real UUIDs.

Comment: How to read these 100 UUIDS in subsequent requests

Comment: hope, some of [that](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+collection+tutorial) may be of help

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I have resolved my issue with the help of BeanshellSampler and props.                                                                                                                                                              
 for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
 props.put("uniqueId" + i,UUID.randomUUID().toString());
   
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following [JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction/) combination:

1. [__UUID()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) - to generate the required GUID structures
2. [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) - so each JMeter thread (virtual user) could use its own value
3. [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) - to store the generated value into a JMeter Property
   4- [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) - to read the value from the JMeter Property

Putting everything together:

1. Generate an UUID and store it into a JMeter property:

   ```
   ${__setProperty(ID_${__threadNum},${__UUID},)}
   ```
2. Read the UUID from the JMeter property:

   ```
   ${__P(ID_${__threadNum},)}
   ```

   [image]